# Improve the performance PARTITION OVER DENSE_RANK query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

My starting table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `UserListCheckQueue` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `next_processing_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_id` int NOT NULL,
  `script_id` bigint unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_processed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `employee_id` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `run_idx` (`script_id`,`employee_id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `npt_idx` (`next_processing_time`),
  KEY `employee_id` (`employee_id`)
);
```

This table can build up to 9 million rows

I want this table to emulate a queue for each employee; my calling code will fetch the next 20 rows at a time.

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (
    PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY is_processed ASC, next_processing_time ASC, id ASC
  ) AS job_rank
FROM test.UserListCheckQueue
WHERE is_processed = 0
ORDER BY job_rank
LIMIT 20;
```

The query above does what I want, but takes 20 seconds to run on 9 million rows. Is there an index, or a better query, that would speed this up?

Comment: Do you have an index on your partitioning and ordering columns?

Comment: Try adding this composite key: `(employee_id, is_processed, next_processing_time, id)`

Comment: Why is `is_processed` in the partition when you're only selecting `is_processed = 0`?

Comment: @Barmar - I think that `employee_id` should be last.

Comment: @RickJames I'm not really very practiced with window functions, but it seems like it first needs to partition, then order within that.

Comment: @Barmar - I'm not practiced either.  Maybe the OP will report on which index works better.

Answer (score 0):

Two indexes, with columns in the given order:

```
INDEX(is_processed, next_processing_time, id, employee_id)
```

Comment: The column "job_rank" is not a column in the table. Adding the other index seems to have shaved a second off.

Comment: @SimonBrahan - Oops.  Fixed.